# Anyone have special issue using WSO2?

Tags: integration, wso2, talend

Anyone have any special issue when using WSO2. I'm still looking forward should I use WSO2 or Talend for Integration framework. Anyone have experience using one of them or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ebay the esb casestudy](http://wso2.com/landing/ebay-the-esb-casestudy/?combdate=270711) is a case study which shows how eBay using WSO2 ESB to process more 1 Billion transactions per day...

Answer (score 5):

Selecting an enterprise service bus (ESB) for integration work needs to be done based on few important factors.

- Performance - as the ESB becomes the central hub, it better perform
- Kinds of services to be integrated - do you have all adopters that you need supported by the ESB, like SAP, FIX, HL7 etc.
- Integration language - for e.g. do you need to write Java code or is it easy to deal with using config languages like XML
- Support for monitoring and management
- Development tools

WSO2 ESB is strong in all these fronts, as proven with eBay case study and more over it is open source. You should compare the equivalent aspects in Talend  before making a choice.

Comment: You forgot to disclose that you work for WSO2 as "VP Delivery at WSO2"

Answer (score 4):

We tried WSO2 stack and found we were spending way too much time in just trying to get all the parts and pieces to work together and get installed. Then once we got it up and running, we couldn't figure out how to expose simple database calls as RESTful services. After a few weeks we gave up and tried Talend ESB. We found a demo and lots of others using it and great videos. We got installed and our hello world rest service up in less than 1 hour.

So if you are making a smaller solution, I strongly recommend Talend so far. It also handles load balancing and high performance; however, we haven't gotten that far. BTW, at work I use Oracle SOA suite, and I am a SOA Architect with more than 5 major SOA platforms under my belt such as TIBCO, WebMethods, and GenTran.

Just my humble 2 cents.

Comment: Member for 2 years and 2 months at the time of writing this comment and this "architect" has only answered this question in that entire time. If it took these guys 2 weeks to "figure something out until they gave up", that's more of a concern about the team than the tools in use.

Answer (score 0):

I  faced  some compatibility issues while using with CXF client stack.
some of the WSO2 ESB / Synapse examples  doesn’t  work with CXF client while they work fine with Axis2 client.  You have to make sure you  are using WSO2 ESB supported namespaces for WS-Security , WS-Addressing m WS-Trust etc on client side. As WSO2 ESB/ Synapse is based on Axis2, If you services and/or clients are based on CXF or Sun Metro, it may be easy and less problematic using Talend or Fuse ESBs.

Comment: What do you mean by "WSO2 ESB supported namespaces for WS-Security , WS-Addressing m WS-Trust etc". These are standards, which specify the exact namespaces that must be used. We have not introduced any "WSO2 specific" WS-* headers! We have regularly done interop testing with different frameworks. Can you post any exception stacktraces etc. to see what could be wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Being based on WSO2 carbon platform WSO2 esb provides a lot of security features such as authentication, authorization, confidentiality etc .. as well.

Following articles shows how to do the service integration and apply security with WSO2 ESB.

[WSO2 ESB by Example - Service Chaining](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining),

[Integrate Business Rules with BPEL](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/05/integrate-business-rules-bpel),

[Securing Web Service Integration](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/06/securing-web-service-integration)

Comment: You forgot to disclose that you a WSO2 employee. "WSO2 Inc as a Software Architect"

Answer (score -2):

Basically when comes to opensource ESBs available, wso2 offers you comprehensive package which you can utilize to solve your day today business use cases, by glance wso2 esb comes with variety of features such as.

- Connecting Anything to Anything
- Routing, Mediation & Transformation
- Message, Service, API & Security Gateway
- High Performance, High Availability, Scalability & Stability
  pls visit:
  http://wso2.org/library/articles/2012/03/performance-benchmarking-wso2-esb-different-message-transfer-mechanisms
- Lightweight, Developer Friendly and Easy to Deploy
- Manage & Monitor
  for further details please visit to http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/